# How to rebind/reload/refresh extjs grid with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, extjs4

I am new with ExtJs !!!
  I have a web method which returns data in JSON format my extjs grid get's bind on page load itself.I am currently making a ajax request to the web method which return me the json data which need to be bind in the Extjs Grid.I have no idea how i can rebind the grid with the updated data.Thanks in Advance !!!!

Comment: You can get the grids store, and call the .load() method on it. If you pass in a url, and the store is set up with the proper proxy, the grid will mask while waiting for the data, and then unmask when finished.  IF possible, please post some sample code you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a separate ajax request instead of reloading the grid's store, you need to load the data into the grid's store.  That will refresh the grid.  Check out this example of refreshing the grid on demand:  [Ext JS Grid Search with .NET and MySQL Backend](http://jorgeramon.me/2015/ext-js-grid-search-with-net-and-mysql-backend/)

Comment: I am just trying to avoid the page load event.Reloading the grid store will again fire all the page life cycle which i want to avoid, so i made a simple ajax call which returns JSON data now i just want to rebind the data with the current JSON data.A little code will be helpful. :)